# Endeca baseline update is failing: SEVERE: Utility 'rmdir_dgraph-input-old' failed

Tags: atg, endeca, oracle-commerce, endeca-workbench, experience-manager

Baseline update on endeca is failing. Please find the logs below:

```
 INFO: Finished pushing content to dgraph.
 INFO: [AuthoringMDEXHost] Starting shell utility 'rmdir_dgraph-input-old'.
 INFO: [LiveMDEXHostA] Starting shell utility 'cleanDir_local-dgraph-input'.
 INFO: [LiveMDEXHostA] Starting shell utility 'rmdir_dgraph-input-old'.
 SEVERE: Utility 'rmdir_dgraph-input-old' failed. Refer to utility logs in [ENDECA_CONF]/logs/shell on host LiveMDEXHostA.
Occurred while executing line 7 of valid BeanShell script: 


     AuthoringDgraphCluster.copyIndexToDgraphServers();
     AuthoringDgraphCluster.applyIndex();

     LiveDgraphCluster.cleanDirs();
     LiveDgraphCluster.copyIndexToDgraphServers();
     LiveDgraphCluster.applyIndex();




SEVERE: Error executing valid BeanShell script.
Occurred while executing line 19 of valid BeanShell script: 


      Dgidx.run();

      // distribute index, update Dgraphs
      DistributeIndexAndApply.run();

      // Upload the generated dimension values to Workbench
      WorkbenchManager.cleanDirs();



SEVERE: Caught an exception while invoking method 'run' on object 'BaselineUpdate'. Releasing locks.

Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke0 - null
Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.AppControlException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script runBeanShellScript - Error executing valid BeanShell script.
Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.AppControlException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script runBeanShellScript - Error executing valid BeanShell script.
Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.EacComponentControlException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.utility.Utility run - Utility 'rmdir_dgraph-input-old' failed. Refer to utility logs in [ENDECA_CONF]/logs/shell on host LiveMDEXHostA.
INFO: Released lock 'update_lock'.
```

Has anyone seen this type of error before? Please let me know the potential solution. Also Baseline update is taking 2 to 3 hours and then it's failing, it's annoying.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you including inventory in your index?  I have seen this cause performance issues during the baseline index process.

Comment: as the logs suggest, check the logs under [ENDECA_CONF]/logs/shell in LiveMDEXHostA machine. ENDECA_CONF=endeca/PlatformServices/workspace

Answer (score 0):

Check logs under

endeca/PlatformServices/workspace/logs/shell

There should be a log named like appName.rmdir_dgraph-input-old.log

with more info about the error.

Probably a non existing folder is trying to be removed or something like that.

If this is the case just create the folder that the utility is trying to remove and execute baseline again.